# SVG bars graph upside down without rotation

Tags: css, svg, rect

I have an svg rect chart like:

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width:100%;height:100%" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
        <g>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="40%" x="0" y="0" fill="black"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="20%" x="50" y="0" fill="green"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="80%" x="100" y="0" fill="red"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="90%" x="150" y="0" fill="yellow"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="10%" x="200" y="0" fill="pink"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="60%" x="250" y="0" fill="orange"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg> 
</div>
```

What I want to do is to display it upside down. 
The code and a given solution, are coming from http://jsfiddle.net/rhvP8/5/

Although, I want to keep each bar in the same X place. So, rotation approach is not that useful in this case.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation of the **x-axis only** seems be be what you require.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid green;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width:100%;height:100%" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
        <g>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="40%" x="0" y="0" fill="black"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="20%" x="50" y="0" fill="green"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="80%" x="100" y="0" fill="red"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="90%" x="150" y="0" fill="yellow"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="10%" x="200" y="0" fill="pink"></rect>
            <rect  width="14.55" height="60%" x="250" y="0" fill="orange"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```